# UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to use FFmpeg with NDK

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I compiled FFmpeg for android without any issue, but gets unsatisfiedlinkerror when I try to run app on device.

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavfilter
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libswscale
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavcodec libavfilter libavutil libswscale libavformat
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT)/$(TARGET_PLATFORM)/arch-arm/usr/lib \
                -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib \
                -llog \
                -lz \
                -ldl \
                -lgcc \
        -landroid \
        -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

native.c (empty c file. rly!!)

MainActivity.java

```
//Trivial blahblah code
...

static {                                                                                
     System.loadLibrary("avformat");                                                     
     System.loadLibrary("avcodec");
     System.loadLibrary("avutil");
     System.loadLibrary("avfilter");                                                     
     System.loadLibrary("swscale");
     System.loadLibrary("native");
}

...
```

I tried commenting out System.loadLibrary() for ffmpeg stuff, but no luck.

I noticed that when I remove -lavformat -lavcodec ... from Android.mk with loadLibrary()s, then it compiles with empty native.c. However, this results in a compilation error when I attempt to compile some useful code in native.c like: error: undefined reference to 'avformat_open_input' - which gets resolved when I add -lavformat ...

I saw similar postings in stackoverflow and tried a bunch, but no luck. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your logcat from the load of the native libraries to the full UnsatisfiedLinkError message ?

If ffmpeg has been compiled with a shared C++ library, like gnustl_shared, you'll need to integrate it (by setting `APP_STL := gnustl_shared` in **Application.mk**), and load it before the ffmpeg libs.